# How to make Flex Container Divs scale-able (Desktop-> Mobile)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 110px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        
justify-content: space-between; /* could also try with space-around */
        
}

.flex-child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
 
  height: calc(100% - 0px); /* for demonstration purposes, subtracts top and bottom margin from height */
  margin: 20px; /* for demonstration purposes */
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    
    
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <img src="img/Basic.jpg" width="288" height="250" >
      
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <img src="img/Premium 100.jpg" width="288" height="250">
    
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <img src="img/Premium 200.jpg" width="288" height="250">
     
  </div>
</div>
```

Hey guys I have another Flex container related question. My Flex containers work great but they don't scale from my Desktop version to Mobile. Any pointers or Ideas to make them scale correctly? Optimaly I would like them "stack" on Mobile (Also the area I'm focusing on is the "Basic-Premium" sections). First Image is Desktop, second is Mobile as you can see the icon section just gets really small.

[image: DESKTOP]

[image: MOBILE]

Comment: Giving `flex-wrap` a try seems like something you can do. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/

Answer (score 0):

To have them stacked on mobile, you will need to add the following code in your mobile media query. It is a really simple line which just changes the direction that the parent is flexing the children.

```
.flex-container{
    flex-direction: column;
}
```